# What is the meaning of "and yet" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Do I repine, is it all murmuring, or am I sad and lone, and cannot,
> cannot help it? Sometimes when I do feel so, I think it may be wrong,
> and that God will punish me by taking you away; for he is very kind to
> let me write to you, and to give me your sweet letters, but my heart
> wants more. Have you ever thought of it Susie, **and yet** I know you
> have, how much these hearts claim; why I dont believe in the whole,
> wide world, are such hard little creditors - such real little misers,
> as you and I carry with us, in our bosoms every day. I cant help
> thinking sometimes, when I hear about the ungenerous, Heart, keep very
> still - or someone will find you out!

I found this from Emily Dickinson's letter.
I wonder what does "and yet" mean here.

Comment: I'd say what it "means" is something along the lines of *Have you ever thought of it, Susie? [Which I ask] **even though** I know you have [thought of her]*. Noting the lack of a syntactically-required comma before the addressee's name ***Susie*** (which I added in my version), I suggest this particular text shouldn't be treated as a good example of anything.

Comment: ...note that in many such contexts, "literary, dated" ***and yet*** could be directly replaced by, for example, ***but of course*** - conveying exactly the same meaning in a somewhat more modern / colloquial tone.

Comment: https://www.dictionary.com/browse/yet: This is the "conjunction" definition of yet, indicating negation. Could often be replaced with "but," "though," "however," or "nevertheless." This sentence could be rewritten "Have you ever thought of it Susie—but I know you have—..." See also https://grammarist.com/usage/and-yet/